# Jackson Polymorphic de-serializing primitive types

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm using Jackson 1.9.13 and have the following simple classes to serialize/de-serialize

```
public interface Comparable {
    //interfaces definition
}

public class ComparableString implements Comparable {
    protected String member;

    //Constructor and interface implementation etc.

    @JsonValue
    public String getString() { return this.member; }
}

//Many other comparables

public class Checker {
    private Comparable left;
    private Comparable right;
    //Getters & Setters

    public Checker(Comparable left, Comparable right) {
    }
}
```

Now that I constructed such one Checker with two ComparableString (whose values are "A" and "B") and want to serialize it, it works perfectly fine and gives me, e.g.

```
{"left":"A", "right":"B"}
```

But now I want to de-serialize it, it tells me:
Can not construct instance of Comparable, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information.

I understand that it couldn't determine which concrete type should it use when it sees Comparable. So I additionally annotated Comparable interface like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, defaultImpl = ComparableString.class)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ComparableString.class)
    //other comparable types
})
public interface Comparable {
    //interfaces definition
}
```

But now it requires additional type field when de-serialization a primitive (who apparently doesn't have any additional type information around it), and serialization changes too, it becomes something like this:

```
{
    "left":["ComparableString","A"],
    "right":["ComparableString","B"]
}
```

I tried to specify `use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE` then it goes back to the unable to identify which type it is error. Apparently, without the type info around, it couldn't determine which type exactly to use to de-serialize a primitive.

My question is: is it possible to somehow manually mapping primitive de-serialization into one of the Comparable classes? Without sacrificing the simplicity of primitives (no additional field for type in JSON body).